# Spurious dot appearing at lower left with forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I've got this very strange problem with trees I'm drawing in `forest`. At the lower-left of every tree I get this spurious, errant dot.

Here's an example:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.10} 
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%   
\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}
} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\tikzset{     
    decision/.style={rectangle, minimum height=10pt, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    chance/.style={circle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    leaf-chance/.style={isosceles triangle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, thick, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, 
shape border rotate=180, outer sep=-\pgflinewidth}   
}

\forestset{
 declare toks={optimality}{},
 declare toks={edge label below}{},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}


\begin{frame}

\scalebox{0.85}{
 \begin{forest}    
    my label/.style={       
        edge label={node[auto, sloped,pos=.75,anchor=south]{#1}}
    },
    my below/.style={
        edge label below={node[midway,below, pos = 0.75, font = \scriptsize,align = center]{#1}}
        %edge label={node[auto, sloped,pos=1.75,anchor=south]{#1}}
    },
    for tree={
      grow=0,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=west,
      text ragged,
      inner sep=1mm,
      edge={thick, draw=black},
      l sep+=30mm,
      s sep+=5mm,
      if n children=0{
        before typesetting nodes={
          label/.wrap pgfmath arg={right:#1}{content()},
          content={},
          leaf-chance,
        },
      }{},
      edge path={
       \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label below}\forestoption{edge label};
  },
    }
    [, decision, label = left: HIV in Liberia,
        [,chance,my label=Treat all, label = right: 25.1
            [25, my label = HIV$^-$, my below = 0.985, tier = word]
            [30, my label = HIV$^+$, my below = 0.015, tier = word]
        ]
        [,chance,my label=Test all, label = right: 34.8
            [,chance, my label = HIV$^-$, my below = 0.985, label = above right: 34.9
                [35, my label= Test$^-\rightarrow$ Don't treat, my below = 0.99, tier = word]
                [25, my label = Test$^+\rightarrow$ Treat, my below = 0.01, tier = word] 
            ]
            [,chance, my label = HIV$^+$, my below = 0.015, label = above right: 28.6
                [2,  my label= Test$^-\rightarrow$ Don't treat, my below = 0.05, tier = word]
                [30, my label = Test$^+\rightarrow$ Treat, my below = 0.95, tier = word] 
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest} }
\end{frame}

\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

which produces the following tree:
[image: Tree diagram with errant dot in SW corner]

See that dot in the SW corner? It's there in every single tree in my document. I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Thank you!

Comment: please fix your example so that people can run it to see the issue. given `\begin{frame}` I guessed adding `\documentclass{beamer}` but that still produced multiple errors. (if you get errors ask about the error not about the output).

Comment: I get no stray period after: removing the `center` environment that makes no sense; adding the option `fragile` to `\begin{frame}`. There is a lot of white space at the left of the tree, which should be cured.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I were getting errors, I would have asked about the errors. I'm getting the output, hence the question about the output.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg.  That worked.

Comment: In that case your file is not as posted as that generated errors hence my question

Comment: I apologize that the file—which I copied and pasted directly—is causing you errors, @DavidCarlisle. It isn't causing errors here, so I don't really know what to tell you.

Comment: The file as posted clearly causes errors, it has no `\documentclass`   I guessed adding `\documentclass{beamer}` but then I still got multiple errors  so I posted the comment above. It would be better if the example was a complete file, so guessing not needed.

Comment: I love that you're sticking to this, @DavidCarlisle. I don't know how else to say this, except: **this file does not generate errors**. Thanks, though. You've been _super_ helpful.

Comment: I don't know how else to say this, the example you have posted above  above starts with `\usepackage` and generates multiple errors, starting with `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.`

Comment: Glad you really want to double down on this. **You are getting an error I'm not getting**. It's really that simple.  Really, really that simple. And also, your insistence on this isn't helpful in the slightest. Why do we need to debug why _you're_ getting an error? Pose it as your own question, then.